# retrieve data from database without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

When the user press entre the data will be save into database.

**Ajax**

```
    $('td.edit').keydown(function(event){


    arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
     var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;
     account_id=document.getElementById("account_id").value;


     if(event.which == 13)
     { 

$.ajax({    type: "POST",
                        url:"clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
                        data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&clientid="+clientid+"&account_id="+account_id,
                        success: function(data){

                        $('#CPH_GridView1_Status').append(data);
                        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                                }});
                                 }

                              }
```

**Html**

```
<td  id="CPH_GridView1_Status'.$rows['net_id'].'" class="edit2 status '.$rows["net_id"].' "><img  src="image/'.$rows["status"].'f.png" /></td>
```

After success I want to retrieve data from database and place it in the proper td ( in the same row of the clicked td) i am success to retrieve data but not retrieve in the correct td

Comment: Use the `context:` option to `$.ajax()` to send context to the `success` function that identifies the row.

Comment: You have just to display it in the resulted page of your AJAX call and take it from the data sent back by your AJAX call.

Comment: `$(this)` pointer should be still pointing to the clicked td, so why dont you use that to set the data back on to the event generated td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which row you want to load data?
change it:

```
$('#CPH_GridView1_Status').append(data);
```

to

```
$('#CPH_GridView1_Status'+arr[2]).append(data);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it worked but if i add again it showing more than one data it not clearing the previous data can you tell me how to clear the previous data when new data is addes

Comment: use html instead of append: $('#CPH_GridView1_Status'+arr[2]).html(data);

Comment: please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262515/how-to-assign-the-retrieved-data-to-the-different-td and please provide me you suggestion thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before appending data first clear current '' using

```
$('#CPH_GridView1_Status'+arr[2]).empty();
```

and then append data

```
$('#CPH_GridView1_Status'+arr[2]).append(data);
```