# how to assign the retrieved data to the different td using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

When the user press button the data will be save into database.After success I want to retrieve data from database and place it in the proper td ( in the same row of the clicked td) i am success to retrieve data but not assign the retrieved data to the different td

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.edit2').on('click', function(){


         arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
        var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;

        $.ajax({    type: "POST",
        url:"clientnetworkpricelist/updateprice.php", 
        data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&clientid="+clientid,
        success: function(data){
                            $('#CPH_GridView1_clientprice'+arr[2]).empty();
                            $('#CPH_GridView1_clientprice'+arr[2]).append(data);                                                             
                            $('.ajax').html($(this).val());
                            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                }});

                                  }  
                             );
                        });
```

**HTML**

```
<td  id="CPH_GridView1_clientprice'.$rows['net_id'].'" class="edit clientprice '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["clientprice"].'</td>
 <td  id="CPH_GridView1_Status'.$rows['net_id'].'" class="edit2 status '.$rows["net_id"].' "><img  src="image/'.$rows["status"].'f.png" /></td>
```

in my updateprice.php i connect to database and retrieve value from the database any just print the retrieve  value like this

```
print $newclientprice;

   print $status;
```

my result

both the value are showing now in the same td but i want it in separate td  0/01 in clientprice and increase in status

```
Client Price      status
 0.01increase    |
                 |
                 |
```

any one help me thanks.

Comment: Show what data returned in ajax-request to `updateprice.php`? I think you should return json and put one item in `CPH_GridView1_clientprice`, and another to `CPH_GridView1_status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### updateprice.php

let's change this:

```
<?php
print $newclientprice;
print $status;
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Because you are using jQuery, let's make use of JSON for our benefit. **Important:** the following code depends on **no output** being sent before it executes, **and** it will finish the php execution immediately

```
<?php
// set type so client can understand what was sent
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// transform our 2 values into a JSON array,
// this will be transparently transformed into an array for your ajax handler
echo json_encode(array($newclientprice, $status));
// end the script, this is what the client ajax request wanted
exit;
```

### javascript.js

I took the liberty to rewrite your code so that it would seem clearer, and at least with a few comments too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var onClick, ajaxSuccessHandleMaker;
  onClick = function() {
    var
      url = 'clientnetworkpricelist/updateprice.php',
      clientid = $('#client')[0].value,
      classesArray = $(this).attr('class').split(" "),
      // send data as object, jQuery will transparently transform for the server
      data = {
        value : $('.ajax input').val,
        rowid : classesArray[2],
        field : classesArray[1],
        clientid : clientid
      };
    // send POST request and expect JSON
    $.post(url,data,ajaxSuccessHandleMaker(classesArray),'json');
  };
  // success returns the ajax handler with a closure on classesArray
  ajaxSuccessHandleMaker = function (arr) {
    // the handler EXPECTS an array, which is why we have to protect output in updateprice.php
    return function (arrayOf2vals) {
      $('#CPH_GridView1_clientprice'+arr[2]).html(arrayOf2vals[0]);
      $('#CPH_GridView1_Status'+arr[2]).html(arrayOf2vals[1]);
      // I am not sure what you want with the following 2 lines of code
      $('.ajax').html($(this).val());// what is this?
      $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');// what is this?
    };
  };
  // set the onClick handler
  $('.edit2').click(onClick);
});
```

### Finally

- any questions are welcome
- please test if it works, if it doesn't then comment back and I'll try to help out